# How can I copy an entire row from a vector of vector to another vector of vector?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<int> selection(std::vector<int> fitness, int num_of_parents, 
std::vector<std::vector<int>> population)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> parents;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_parents; ++i)
    {

        int max_fitness_index;
        max_fitness_index = reinterpret_cast<int>(*std::max_element(fitness.begin(), fitness.end()));
        parents.at(i).push_back(population.at(max_fitness_index));

  }
}
```

In the above code, What I am trying to do is move the row of the population vector which will be calculated by max_fitness_index.

As of now, I haven't figured it out yet.

Second Edit:  I am trying to reimplement the python code from [here](https://medium.com/koderunners/genetic-algorithm-part-3-knapsack-problem-b59035ddd1d6) in C++.
Which has all the code present.

Comment: That `reinterpret_cast` looks really scary. Why not `max_fitness_index = std::max_element(fitness.begin(), fitness.end()) - fitness.begin();`?

Comment: @alterigel got rid of the  `reinterpret_cast` now the about the main question?

Comment: The word "move" can be ambiguous since it has its colloquial meaning and a technical C++ meaning. You are currently copying a row from `population` to `parents`. This could be changed to C++ move semantics simply by declaring that a move is allowed via `std::move` and `emplace_back`. Did you want to additionally remove the row from `population` (the colloquial meaning of "move")? Wouldn't that mess up the index obtained by from `fitness`?

Comment: By the way, your "For example" part seems to be missing something as it establishes a dimension of 5x7 but never makes use of that.

Comment: I believe what you want in your for loop is `parents.push_back(population.at(max_fitness_index));`

Comment: Is a `vector`really what you want when you shuffle stuff around like this? A [mre] may spawn some new ideas.

Comment: @JaMiT yup, made a mistake in the explanation. Edited that. I just wanted to copy things.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Did the job, now just have to test my code and will comment back.

Comment: Another question would be why do you want to calculate `max_fitness_index` in every iteration of the for loop. It would always have the same result, and make you push_back the same data into `parents`

Comment: Do you mean to find the second highest in the second iteration? If that's the case, then `parents` would be just the reversed `population` if `fitness.size() == population.size()` and `fitness.size() == num_of_parents`

Comment: @gigakb I still don't see why "5x7" is important to the example. In fact, your "edit" section seems to be redundant with the example just before it (other than explicitly saying that a copy will be made).

Comment: Hmm... are you merely trying to figure out why the line `parents.at(i).push_back(population.at(max_fitness_index));` does not compile? If that's the case, you should have copied the text of the error message into your question and focused on that. Explain what that line is supposed to do, and potentially simplify your example by getting rid of the loop (initialize `max_fitness_index` to an arbitrary value, as in `int max_fitness_index = 1; // Obtained from a function in real code.`).

Comment: the 5x7 is just an example. In the second edit, I have mentioned what I am trying to actually do. The author there in my opinion has done a terrible job of explanation. @JaMiT . What this exact section doing is selecting the best (max) value, and passing its index (as per the python code ), and copying the `vector` from `population`  at the calculated index.

Comment: @gigakb Yes, the 5x7 is "just" an example, and one that has no bearing on anything else in the question. You could remove the two sentences that mention the 5x7 dimensions, and lose nothing from the question. There is no additional insight gained from knowing the exact dimensions, so why mention them at all?